# Trying To Get List To Only List Items With Matching ClientId

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the list view to list only contracts with a matching ClientId.

```
public ActionResult Contracts()
        {
            //Get Logged In UserId
            var sessionid = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();

            //Set Client By Logged In UserId
            var client = _context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == sessionid);

            //Set Contracts To Matching ClientId
            var contract = _context.Contracts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == client.ClientId);

            //Add Contracts To List
            var contracts = _context.Contracts.ToList();

            return View(contracts);
            
        }
```

As you can see in the code above, first, I get the Asp.Net UserId from the logged in session.  Then, I find the Client with a matching UserId, and finally, I find the contracts with a matching ClientId.  When I run the program, it still ends up showing all the contracts instead of just those with the matching Id.

I am new to this and experimenting my way through a lot of it, so forgive my ignorance.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, for starters, you're not using `contract` in anything you're passing to the View. It should be something like: `var contracts = _context.Contracts.Where(c => c.ClientId == client.ClientId).ToList();`

Comment: Have you noticed that there is both a variable named contract and one named contracts?

Comment: @itsme86 thats it!  thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using LINQ by saying

```
var contracts = _context.Contracts.Where(contract => contract.ClientId == client.ClientId).ToList();
```

Right now, you're only getting the first contract with a matching client ID, and then you're adding the entire contracts group to a list.